# Trigger d3 update when node data changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data (can be several thousand nodes) which looks something like this which is bound in d3:

```
{ 
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2
    ...
}
```

There are times where `key1` may be modified while others where `key2` changes. How can I tell d3 to redraw the modified elements when I call `data` with this new content?

In the following example, if one of the key fields change in the `inputData` then I would like to call this code in order to trigger redraw of the affected items:

```
svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(inputData, function (d) { return d; });
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', function(d) { 
        if(d.key1 === 1) return 'node-class-A'
        else if(d.key2 === 2) return 'node-class-B'
        // etc
    });
```

Comment: before binding filter your data on being modified and use a useful key function, read the Update-Pattern doc again.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you rephrase that?

Comment: that's why I said that you should read the docs. If you know how the Data Bind works you would understand. And there are good articles and SO answers about Data Bind, and not so good. And we don't know which version of D3 you use.

Answer (score 0):

See https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 for the General Update pattern for D3 implemented for a Force-layout. As long as you are drawing your graph in this way, you can just call the update function to redraw the graph with the updated data.

Just call update in some sort of listener off of whatever is changing the data, be it a text input, button, select box, etc...